# Not picking up a variable within an if statement.

Tags: php, mysql

```
if($_FILES['fileField']['tmp_name']!= "") {

$newname="$fid.jpg";
echo $newname;
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileField']['tmp_name'],"images/covers/$newname");
    }
```

I am trying to get a image to update however the id variable is not being recognised

> Notice: Undefined variable: targetID in D:\shares\Student\web\soft20171\N0431485\Film on Time - Updated\update_movie.php on line 125
>   '.jpg
>
> Warning: move_uploaded_file(images/covers/'
>
> **Notice**: Undefined variable: targetID in **D:\shares\Student\web\soft20171\N0431485\Film on Time - Updated\update_movie.php** on line **125**
>  '.jpg): failed to open stream: Invalid argument in D:\shares\Student\web\soft20171\N0431485\Film on Time - Updated\update_movie.php on line 64
>
> Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move 'C:\WINDOWS\Temp\php372.tmp' to 'images/covers/'
>
> **Notice**: Undefined variable: targetID in **D:\shares\Student\web\soft20171\N0431485\Film on Time - Updated\update_movie.php** on line **125**
>  '.jpg' in D:\shares\Student\web\soft20171\N0431485\Film on Time - Updated\update_movie.php on line 64

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

I'll provide you with a working sample I've already helped another person with, this will correct your issue:

```
<?php
if(isset($_FILES['userfile'])){

$uploaddir = '/var/www/test/uploads/'; // path to be uploaded
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
        if (!file_exists($uploaddir)) {
            mkdir($uploadDir, 0777, true);
        }

echo "<p>";

// Error Checking Extended
    if($_FILES['userfile']['error'] == 2) {
    echo "You've exceeded the maximum file upload size of 512kb.";
    return false;
    }

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
  echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
} else {
   echo "Upload failed";
}

echo "</p>";
echo '<pre>';
echo 'Here is some more debugging info:';
print_r($_FILES);
print "</pre>";
} else {
?>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="512000" />
    Send this file: <input name="userfile" type="file" />
    <input type="submit" value="Send File" />
</form>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: I am still confused the problem I am having is that the hidden variable from my form is not returning and therefore the $newname file  is wrong so it cannot update how do they relate ?

Comment: Because your code isn't sufficient to assist you other than saying your variable after your IF statement is the first time we see it initialized and assigned a value $newname="$fid.jpg"; and we don't know where that value came from, so providing you with a fully functioning sample you can visually see what's going on. I suggest you check the PHP documentation as well: http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php